# Show that integral operator of positive definite kernel is positive.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

Assume that $\chi$ is a compact metric space with finite measure $\mu$. Suppose we have a continuous positive definite kernel $k$ as described above.

Then we can define $$T_f(x)=\int k(x,y)f(y)d\mu$$ where $f\in L_2(\chi)$.

I would like to show that $<f,T_f> \geq 0$ for all $f\in L_2(\chi)$.

Does anyone know how to prove this. I know I need to prove that $$\int\int k(x,y)f(x)f(y)d\mu d\mu\geq 0$$ but I do not know that right way to approximate this integral to prove the statement. Do we have to use MCT somehow given the definition of positive definiteness of $k$?

P.S. This is part of the proof of Mercer's Theorem.